# How to customize the header navigation in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I know that the SafeAreaView is just a simple View in react native and when trying to custom the header bar noting works. Here is what I've done so far:
The Stack navigation:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from '../screens/Home';
import Detail from '../screens/Detail';
import NavigationCustom from './NavigationCustom';
import Search from '../screens/Search';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MainNavigation = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode={'screen'}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{
              headerTransparent: true,
            header: ({navigation}) => (
              <NavigationCustom navigation={navigation} main={true} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Detail"
          component={Detail}
          options={{
            headerTransparent: true,
            header: ({navigation}) => (
              <NavigationCustom navigation={navigation} main={false} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

export default MainNavigation

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Now in my NavCustom component I have the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const defaultProps = {
    main: false
}

const NavigationCustom = ({navigation: {goBack, navigate}, main}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      {main ? (
        <View style={styles.mainNav}>
          <Image
            style={styles.logo}
            source={require('../assets/images/movies.png')}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              navigate('Search');
            }}>
            <Icon name={'search-outline'} size={30} color={'blue'} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              goBack();
            }}>
            <Icon name={'chevron-back'} size={40} color={'blue'} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default NavigationCustom

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  mainNav: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    padding: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
});

NavigationCustom.propTypes = {
    main: PropTypes.bool,
}

NavigationCustom.propTypes = defaultProps;
```

The headerTransparent: true, and the header options: are not working and I would like to know the solution.

[image]

I just find a new solution: I refactor my code like the following:

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerTintColor: 'tomato',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
          headerRight: () => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate('Search');
                }}>
                <Icon name={'search-outline'} size={30} color={'blue'} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
```

But now the problem still the navigation because headerRight seems not compatible with **navigation** and return the following error:
**undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigation.navigate')**

Answer (score 1):

I finally find how to do it guys! see the correction below :
Code update: **options={({navigation}) =>**

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerTransparent: true,
            headerTintColor: 'tomato',
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
          headerRight: () => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate('Search');
                }}>
                <Icon name={'search-outline'} size={30} color={'blue'} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          },
        })}
      />
```

Comment: Good work, I spent a while trying to figure this out.